# UpAndroid WebView OnTouchListner throwing Exception

Tags: android, webview, nullpointerexception, touch-event

I have the below code which using `WebView's OnTouchListner`,

```
            wvmmsgoftheday.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {             
                    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                        handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(CLICK_ON_WEBVIEW, 500);
                        return true;
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            });
```

This code works perfect in my Android Mobile version 4.1.0, but I execute the same code Samsung Galaxy Tab Android version 4.0.1 getting Null Pointer Exception.

Can someone help to know what is the reason? OnTouchListner Event have any depending Android version?

## Update - Logcat

```
07-20 14:38:09.998: E/AndroidRuntime(12617): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-20 14:38:09.998: E/AndroidRuntime(12617): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-20 14:38:09.998: E/AndroidRuntime(12617):    at com.eptechtalk.BeforeLogin$Message_Of_The_Day.onPostExecute(BeforeLogin.java:550)
07-20 14:38:09.998: E/AndroidRuntime(12617):    at com.eptechtalk.BeforeLogin$Message_Of_The_Day.onPostExecute(BeforeLogin.java:1)
07-20 14:38:09.998: E/AndroidRuntime(12617):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
07-20 14:38:09.998: E/AndroidRuntime(12617):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
07-20 14:38:09.998: E/AndroidRuntime(12617):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
07-20 14:38:09.998: E/AndroidRuntime(12617):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-20 14:38:09.998: E/AndroidRuntime(12617):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-20 14:38:09.998: E/AndroidRuntime(12617):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
07-20 14:38:09.998: E/AndroidRuntime(12617):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-20 14:38:09.998: E/AndroidRuntime(12617):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-20 14:38:09.998: E/AndroidRuntime(12617):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:978)
07-20 14:38:09.998: E/AndroidRuntime(12617):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
07-20 14:38:09.998: E/AndroidRuntime(12617):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Paste the logcat (full stack trace). The problem is after click?

Comment: No, the problem when initially loads the Webview

Comment: Post onPostExecute method and mark with comment of something else line: 550

Comment: omg... this return null "wvmsgofthedaylogin = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvmsgofdaylogin); " its strange, but how its working fine in Mobile device?

Comment: Maybe you have a different layout in layout-large or layout-xlarge. The phone do not search this directories.

Comment: Ohh...yes, I didn't notice that, actually I fix bug for someones application. Thanks a lot dude.